# Node.js: Append to file without closing handle

Tags: node.js

I have blog, written in Node.js, without Express... I want to implement access logs.

I want to store the logs in JSON. There are 2 problems: first, I don't want to open file handle to access log file, write to it, and then close it. I would like to just open it on server startup, and write to it and close it when I shut the server. Is it possible? Is it actually effective?

Second problem: I want to append new log instead of writing whole file. Logs are in form of an array. Is there any way rewrite closing bracket of the array (`]`) with, add log object behind it and add `]` to end?

Comment: Why an array? Line-oriented seems easier, even if each line is json. And of course you could open a file on app startup, like during a module's initialization, and keep using it during operation.

Comment: In addition to @DaveNewton's point about line-oriented being easier, it will be better in the long run. I'm assuming you are considering reading the log at some point. When you do that you will want to use a buffered stream, and read a few kilobytes at a time. You won't want to read a huge log file all into memory. If you are planning to read that array at some point and `JSON.parse` it you need the whole array to be loaded into memory at once for it to be meaningful (twice! first as a string and then again as an array after parsing).

Comment: @Paulpro actually, it's quite possible to lazy read huge JSON array. Guys from mongodb did it in `mongoimport` utility. Though, [it took them half a year to do so](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7355). =)

Comment: Consider Common Log Format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format, e.g. `127.0.0.1 user-identifier frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326`

Answer (score 2):

### Open file once, write multiple times

> first, I don't want to open file handle to access log file, write to
>   it, and then close it. I would like to just open it on server startup,
>   and write to it and close it when I shut the server. Is it possible?
>   Is it actually effective?

Yes, it's possible and effective. The best solution for you is to [open `WriteStream`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) once and then write all your data using its [`.write()` method](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback):

```
var log = fs.createWriteStream('./my.log', {
  flags: 'a' // Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not exist.
})

log.write('Application started');
```

It's much safer than handling file descriptor by yourself, because, [as said in `fs.write` documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback):

> Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.write` multiple times on the same file
>   without waiting for the callback. For this scenario,
>   `fs.createWriteStream` is strongly recommended.

---

### Appending file instead of rewriting it

> I want to append new log instead of writing whole file

Just use append flag `a` instead of default write flag `w`. For more info [see `fs.open` docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

---

### Append JSON array

> Logs are in form of an array. Is there any way rewrite closing bracket
>   of the array (`]`) with, add log object behind it and add `]` to end?

It is a very bad idea to store your logs in such format.

The whole idea of logging is to be able to quickly spit your logs into some log file. You'll need to write quite complicated logic to properly remove and then recreate closing bracket `]`.

Of course, it's possible. But not doing so is a much better solution.